# Getting a space character in output, when counting characters from input

Tags: c#, collections, console, character

I've been working with this for a few days and I am trying to complete a console application where we are prompted to type in a string of our own and the output makes a list of every unique character and puts a count after it.  At the end of the results, a count is displayed showing how many unique characters were found.  Everything is translated to lowercase despite whether it is uppercase or not.  They key is to use collections.  Here is what I have so far.  My output shows two space characters in the results despite the fact that I used an if statement to catch them.  Can anyone point out a concept that I have overlooked?

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class LetterCountTest
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create sorted dictionary based on user input
        SortedDictionary<string, int> dictionary = CollectLetters();

        // display sorted dictionary content
        DisplayDictionary(dictionary);
    } // end Main

    // create sorted dictionary from user input
    private static SortedDictionary<string, int> CollectLetters()
    {
        // create a new sorted dictionary
        SortedDictionary<string, int> dictionary =
           new SortedDictionary<string, int>();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a string: "); // prompt for user input
        string input = Console.ReadLine(); // get input

        // split every individual letter for the count
        string[] letters = Regex.Split(input, "");

        // processing input letters
        foreach (var letter in letters)
        {
            string letterKey = letter.ToLower(); // get letter in lowercase
            if (letterKey != " ") // statement to exclude whitespace count
            {
                // if the dictionary contains the letter
                if (dictionary.ContainsKey(letterKey))
                {
                    ++dictionary[letterKey];
                } // end if
                else
                    // add new letter with a count of 1 to the dictionary
                    dictionary.Add(letterKey, 1);
            }
        } // end foreach

        return dictionary;
    } // end method CollectLetters

    // display dictionary content
    private static void DisplayDictionary<K, V>(
       SortedDictionary<K, V> dictionary)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nSorted dictionary contains:\n{0,-12}{1,-12}",
           "Key:", "Value:");

        // generate output for each key in the sorted dictionary
        // by iterating through the Keys property with a foreach statement
        foreach (K key in dictionary.Keys)
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-12}{1,-12}", key, dictionary[key]);

        Console.WriteLine("\nsize: {0}", dictionary.Count);
        Console.ReadLine();
    } // end method DisplayDictionary
} // end class LetterCountTest
```

My output states that I am using every letter in the alphabet but also has a whitespace above the 'a' and two instances of it.  I don't know where this is coming from, but my guess is that it's counting null characters or carriage returns.  The string that I use is...

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

Aside from counting every letter once, it counts the e three times, the h two times, the o four times, the r two times, the t two times, and the u two times.

Comment: `Regex.Split(input, "");` is better written as `input.ToCharArray()`

Comment: You're getting empty strings at the beginning and end because of your `Regex.Split(input, "")`. Switching to the proposed answer, or changing your if statement to `if (letterKey != " " && letterKey != "")` should fix the problem

Comment: You're the man Will =)
It runs as intended now that I added the other condition.  I wasn't sure what it was doing, but now I understand.  Thanks again for your help everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem your having relies in `Regex.Split()`'s behavior. Taking an excerpt from [the msdn page on the method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)...

> If a match is found at the beginning or the end of the input string, an empty string is included at the beginning or the end of the returned array.

This is exactly what is happening when you call `Regex.Split(input, "");`. To combat this, you can remove the regex matching from your code, change all instances of your dictionaries to a `SortedDictionary<char, int>`, and use a `foreach` loop to iterate through each character of your input string instead.

```
foreach (char letter in input.ToLower())
{
    if (!Char.IsWhiteSpace(letter))
    {
         //Do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great take on it actually.  I'm going to play around with this and make sure that I understand.  You've been a big help.  Thanks for helping me think outside the box.

Comment: Not a problem! A little debugging and reading up on the MSDN can really go a long way :)

Answer (score 0):

Since a `string` is already an array or characters you don't need that `Regex.Split`, just use:

```
foreach (var letter in input)
```

Then change your  `if` statement to:

```
 foreach (var letter in input)
 {
     if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(letter))
     {
         var letterKey = letter.ToString();

         if (dictionary.ContainsKey(letterKey))
         {
             ++dictionary[letterKey];
         } 
         else
             dictionary.Add(letterKey, 1);
    }
}
```

Then it should exclude the empty strings and the white-spaces.I suspect you get some empty strings after `Regex.Split`, and you checking for only *white-space* therefore you get unexpected results.If you work with `chars` the you don't need to worry about empty strings.